# Can't view network plugins.php or upgrade-core.php on multisite

Tags: multisite, 404-error

I have a network with 5 or 6 sites. In the network admin panel I can see all pages except the /wp-admin/network/plugins.php page and the /wp-admin/network/upgrade-core.php page. Both of those files exist when viewing the folder structure, but for some reason they won't load. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on multisite 3.9.It was a plugin issue (from one or multiple plugins). Went on ftp, created a new folder in wp-content called 'Plugintest', transfered all plugins from 'plugin' folder to 'plugintest' folder and I was able to go to plugin in Admin panel.
Then put back plugins 1 by 1 into 'plugin' folder (on FTP) and check if it still work on admin panel after each transfer. If it works and plugin has an available update, do it right away.
once all the plugoins are back in your 'plugin' folder you can erase 'plugintest'.
Hope it works!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I got also 404 from update-core.php but also when I tried to go to the plugins page (might have been few other pages in the admin panel). I found out that some of the files in wp-admin directory had privileges 646 instead of 644. After changing that everything seems to work again...